# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Database(table)

Tags: java, jpa, select

I want to bring data from databases into 'selectoneoption' but I didn't.
I have citys into citys table in database. Users can select one city in selectonemenu. This is my aim. Thanks.
Here is JSF code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="adres" value="#{loginController.iller}" class="form-control">
                        <f:selectItems itemValue ="#{loginController.il}" itemLabel="#{loginController.il}" ></f:selectItems>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Here is controller class

```
public loginController()
{
    iller = l.il_getir();

    //For test -----
    login l  = new login();
    System.out.println(il);
    System.out.println(iller.size());
    for(int i = 0; i<l.il_getir().size();i++)
    {
        iller = l.il_getir();
        System.out.println(iller.get(i));
    }

}
```

I am tried 'SELECT c from citys c' but it is not work. Here is Dao Codes

```
public class login implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
EntityManager em;
EntityManagerFactory emf;
private List<Citys> iller = new ArrayList<>();

public login()
{
    emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("deneme_kanbagisi_war_0PU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

}
public List<Citys> il_getir()
{
    try
    {
        String sql = "SELECT c.isim FROM Citys c";
        Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
        iller = query.getResultList();

        return iller;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
            {
                return iller;
            }
}

}
```

I want to bring data into selectitems in JSF page but There is a error

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type model.Citys not present
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
.......
```

Also this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Citys
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
... 68 more
```

Also this is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citys")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Citys.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Citys c")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Citys.findByIlNo", query = "SELECT c FROM Citys c WHERE 
c.ilNo = :ilNo")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Citys.findByIsim", query = "SELECT c FROM Citys c WHERE 
c.isim = :isim")})
public class Citys implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "il_no")
private Integer ilNo;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "isim")
private String isim;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ilNo")
private Collection<Villages> villagesCollection;

public Citys() {
}

public Citys(Integer ilNo) {
    this.ilNo = ilNo;
}

public Integer getIlNo() {
    return ilNo;
}

public void setIlNo(Integer ilNo) {
    this.ilNo = ilNo;
}

public String getIsim() {
    return isim;
}

public void setIsim(String isim) {
    this.isim = isim;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Villages> getVillagesCollection() {
    return villagesCollection;
}

public void setVillagesCollection(Collection<Villages> villagesCollection) {
    this.villagesCollection = villagesCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (ilNo != null ? ilNo.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are 
not set
    if (!(object instanceof Citys)) {
        return false;
    }
    Citys other = (Citys) object;
    if ((this.ilNo == null && other.ilNo != null) || (this.ilNo != null && 
   !this.ilNo.equals(other.ilNo))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "model.Citys[ ilNo=" + ilNo + " ]";
}

}
```

Comment: Also ı dont need bring data ıd so ı can bring data string format. And maybe ı can use String.join method but ı cant. Just I imagine..

Comment: In addition. this is showing how get data in selectitems from database but he is using List<String>. But ı have database type. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tgmjkVa8Gc

Comment: You can edit your question and add this info there. And the error is clear (and totally not JSF related. Class cannot be found... Oh and the class in the title is another one than in the text...

Comment: oo sorry but ı have class in model package.